# Seo friendly url for specific page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make a specific page url to user friendly

I have a page www.example.com/index.php?route=a/b

Which I want to be rewritten as -> www.example.com/a

I used this rule in htacces but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^/a$ index.php?route=a/b
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^a/?$ /index.php?route=a/b [L,NC,QSA]
```

And remember that inside `.htaccess` leading slash in URI is not matched so `^a/?$` instead of `^/a/?$`.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)